# Cycling through a list of values for Group Names to Process

Tags: list, powershell, split, pipeline

I am trying to get the PowerShell syntax right to create a list of AD group names which I can then go on to loop through and process.  The working code for *one* named group is :

```
$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -identity "My_Group_Name" |
          select name -expandproperty name)
```

They split this AD group into 8 sub-groups, so requirements now dictate that

```
`$Groups` is a list of 8 known groups.  So I am aiming for something like:

$GroupList = "My_Group_Name1,My_Group_Name2,My_Group_Name3,My_Group_Name4";
$Groups = $GroupList.split(",");
$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -identity ***each group member of $Groups*** |
          select name -expandproperty name)
```

It's the bit that does `***each group member of $Groups***` I am struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$Groups = $GroupList.split(",");
$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -identity ***each group member of $Groups*** |
          select name -expandproperty name)
```

into this:

```
$Groups = $GroupList.Split(",") | Get-ADGroupMember |
          Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Better yet, define `$GroupList` as an array right away (as [@Chard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36173470/1630171) suggested), so you don't need to split a string in the first place:

```
$GroupList = 'My_Group_Name1', 'My_Group_Name2', 'My_Group_Name3',
             'My_Group_Name4'
$Groups = $GroupList | Get-ADGroupMember | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies all.  I have the code working now.

@Ansgar, that is exactly what I was thinking about - just getting the pipeline thing straight in my head.

The Group loop processing wasn't shown for brevity.  That was the harder part as they now want the group names inserted as a column for every member row, to make pasting into Excel easier etc.  Worked it out.

Thanks again for all replies.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$GroupList = "My_Group_Name1","My_Group_Name2","My_Group_Name3","My_Group_Name4" 
$GroupMembers = @()

$GroupList | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupMembers += (Get-AdGroup -identity $_ | Get-ADGroupMember | select -expandproperty name)
}

$GroupMembers
```

I wouldn't use one string to store all of your group names, try using an array of strings and then you will not need to use the split command. The code above will take an array of group names and add the memebrs of them to the variable `$GroupMembers`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your array of groups.

> foreach ($group in $grouplist) {
>
> ```
>   your code here
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

```
$Grouplist = @(
"group1",
"group2"
)

foreach($group in $Grouplist){    
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $group |select name -expandproperty name 
}
```